# Changing the compiler's classpath from a Scala macro?

Tags: scala, macros, classpath, scala-2.10

Say we wanted to build a feature like `require`, which is known in many scripting languages, in Scala.

If we require a library like this...

```
require("some-library.jar")
```

... we would need a way to add this jar to the compiler's classpath when the require macro is executed. How can this be done?

Comment: You can try adapting this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010919/adding-files-to-java-classpath-at-runtime

Comment: That is about changing the runtime classpath, so not what I need.

Comment: But if it is in the definition of the macro (_not_ the generated code), it should be run by the compiler, and change _its_ runtime classpath.

Comment: Yeah, but the runtime classpath of the compiler is still not the compilation classpath. Is it?

Comment: I thought it was while writing that comment, but on further thought that should be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another interesting @kim-stebel question.

My first idea, which doesn't address your question, is that your compiler can customize the macro classpath with findMacroClassLoader.  The REPL uses that thanks to @extempore.

That would be useful for an idiom like requiring("myfoo.jar") { mymacro }, perhaps.

Your question is whether you can update the compiler's classpath. That may be possible by casting down from your context universe to the compiler, for which isCompilerUniverse == true.  Then you can platform.updateClassPath.

Update with code:

Here is something like that idea of using a special placeholder in the class path for the required macro.

The fancy way, mentioned below, would be to use a custom class path that can report all the required classes at that location. The old code mentioned below was for a virtual directory in the class path.

This quick and cheesy way uses the file system to unpack your jar and just asks the compiler to rescan it.

The placeholder has to be an actual dir due to a limitation in invalidateClassPathEntries, which wants to check if the canonical file path is on the class path.

```
package alacs

import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.Context

import scala.sys.process._
import java.io.File

/** A require macro to dynamically fudge the compilation classpath.  */
object PathMaker {
  // special place to unpack required libs, must be on the initial classpath
  val entry = "required"

  // whether to report updated syms without overly verbose -verbose
  val talky = true

  def require(c: Context)(name: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._
    val st = c.universe.asInstanceOf[scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable]
    if (st.isCompilerUniverse) {
      val Literal(Constant(what: String)) = name.tree
      if (update(what)) {
        val global = st.asInstanceOf[scala.tools.nsc.Global]
        val (updated, _) = global invalidateClassPathEntries entry
        c.info(c.enclosingPosition, s"Updated symbols $updated", force = talky)
      } else {
        c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Couldn't unpack '$what' into '$entry'")
      }
    }
    reify { () }
  }

  // figure out where name is, and update the special class path entry
  def update(name: String): Boolean = {
    // Process doesn't parse the command, it just splits on space,
    // something about working on Windows
    //val status = s"sh -c \"mkdir $entry ; ( cd $entry ; jar xf ../$name )\"".!

    // but Process can set cwd for you
    val command = s"jar xf ../$name"
    val status = Process(command, new File(entry)).!
    (status == 0)
  }
}
```

The required require API:

```
package alacs

import scala.language.experimental.macros

object Require {
  def require(name: String): Unit = macro PathMaker.require
}
```

Usage:

```
package sample

import alacs.Require._

/** Sample app requiring something not on the class path. */
object Test extends App {
  require("special.jar")
  import special._
  Console println Special(7, "seven")
}
```

Something packaged in special.jar

```
package special

case class Special(i: Int, s: String)
```

Tested this way:

```
rm -rf required
mkdir required
skalac pathmaker.scala
skalac -cp .:required require.scala sample.scala
skala -cp .:special.jar sample.Test

apm@mara:~/tmp/pathmaker$ . ./b
Unpack special.jar
sample.scala:8: Updated symbols List(package special)
  require("special.jar")
         ^
Special(7,seven)
```

The macro doesn't sneak it onto the runtime path, which is the scripty thing to do.

But I suppose the require macro could do handy things like conditionally grab different versions of a jar, with differing compile-time characteristics (constants, etc).

Update, just verifying that it's pretty wild:

```
  require("fast.jar")
  import constants._
  Console println speed

  require("slow.jar")
  Console println speed
```

where

```
package object constants {
  //final val speed = 55
  final val speed = 85
}

$ skalac -d fast.jar constants.scala
```

and running it with inlined constants

```
85
55
```

New caveat: this is my first macro, and I'm looking at invalidateClassPathEntries for another application, so I haven't explored limitations yet.

Update: one limitation is controlling when the macro is expanded.  I wanted to show how something compiles against old api vs new api, and had to wrap the code in blocks to make sure symbols are available before needed:

```
require("oldfoo.jar")
locally {
  import foo._
  // something
  require("newfoo.jar")
  // try again
}
```

Old caveat:
Sorry for the vague answer, I know you don't abide that; I'll try it out later, but meantime maybe someone will step forward with clarity.

Previously, I've hooked into the "platform" implementation for the compiler global, but that's hopefully overkill for this use case.  At that point, you can do whatever you want with the classpath, but I think you want something more out-of-the-box.

Comment: @som-snytt could you please expand with code examples on how you can use the compiler global to completely modify the classpath, all the values in the scala.tools.nsc.Global class seem immutable.

Comment: @RicardoGladwell The mutable thing is the class path itself. In this solution, the file system is used to update the contents of a location, and the compiler is asked to refresh that location.  It's also possible to instantiate a global with a custom ClassPath implementation and do the equivalent virtually, but it's not elegant.  There is an effort underway to improve the ClassPath abstraction.

Comment: @som-snytt if i get hold of the URLClassLoader from the macroClassLoader and modify the state of this by adding additional JAR URLs, would that work?

Comment: @RicardoGladwell Let me know when you've tried it. You can tell it what class loader to use for macros, see what the REPL does.

Answer (score 0):

As Eugene Burmanko states in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630366/scala-macros-add-function-to-class), definitions can currently (Scala 2.10) not be added/removed outside the macro. If you are willing to use [macro paradise](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html), there might be a way.

Comment: If I understand Eugene's answer correctly, he is just referring to definitions _created_ by the macro. Also, "there might be a way" is not exactly what I was looking for in an answer. ;)