# Use Scala macros to generate methods

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-macro-paradise, scalameta

I want to generate aliases of methods using annotation macros in Scala 2.11+. I am not even sure that is even possible. If yes, how?

Example - Given this below, I want the annotation macros to expand into

```
class Socket {
  @alias(aliases = Seq("!", "ask", "read"))
  def load(n: Int): Seq[Byte] = {/* impl */}
}
```

I want the above to generate the synonym method stubs as follows:

```
class Socket {
  def load(n: Int): Seq[Byte] = // .... 
  def !(n: Int) = load(n)
  def ask(n: Int) = load(n)
  def read(n: Int) = load(n)
}
```

The above is of course a facetious example but I can see this technique being useful to auto generate sync/async versions of APIs or in DSLs with lots of synonyms. Is it possible to also expose these generated methods in the Scaladoc too? Is this something possible using Scala meta?

Note: What I am asking is quite different from: https://github.com/ktoso/scala-macro-method-alias

Also please don't mark this as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630366/scala-macros-add-function-to-class) as the question is a bit different and a lot has changed in Scala macro land in past 3 years.

Comment: That seems doable using quasiquotes.  Check out this slide deck from a recent meetup about Macros: https://speakerdeck.com/bwmcadams/ny-scala-meetup-scala-macros-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-mumble-wtf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible exactly as stated. Using a macro annotation on a class member does not allow you to manipulate the tree of the class itself. That is, when you annotate a method within a class with a macro annotation, `macroTransform(annottees: Any*)` will be called, but the only annottee will be the method itself.

I was able to get a proof-of-concept working with two annotations. It's obviously not as nice as simply annotating the class, but I can't think of another way around it.

You'll need:

```
import scala.annotation.{ StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly }
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context
```

The idea is, you can annotate each method with this annotation, so that a macro annotation on the parent class is able to find which methods you want to expand.

```
class alias(aliases: String *) extends StaticAnnotation
```

Then the macro:

```
// Annotate the containing class to expand aliased methods within
@compileTimeOnly("You must enable the macro paradise plugin.")
class aliased extends StaticAnnotation {
    def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro AliasMacroImpl.impl
}

object AliasMacroImpl {

  def impl(c: Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._

    val result = annottees map (_.tree) match {
      // Match a class, and expand.
      case (classDef @ q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }") :: _ =>

        val aliasedDefs = for {
          q"@alias(..$aliases) def $tname[..$tparams](...$paramss): $tpt = $expr" <- stats
          Literal(Constant(alias)) <- aliases
          ident = TermName(alias.toString)
        } yield {
          val args = paramss map { paramList =>
            paramList.map { case q"$_ val $param: $_ = $_" => q"$param" }
          }

          q"def $ident[..$tparams](...$paramss): $tpt = $tname(...$args)"
        }

        if(aliasedDefs.nonEmpty) {
          q"""
            $mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self =>
              ..$stats
              ..$aliasedDefs
            }
          """
        } else classDef
        // Not a class.
        case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Invalid annotation target: not a class")
    }

    c.Expr[Any](result)
  }

}
```

Keep in mind this implementation will be brittle. It only inspects the annottees to check that the first is a `ClassDef`. Then, it looks for members of the class that are methods annotated with `@alias`, and creates multiple aliased trees to splice back into the class. If there are no annotated methods, it simply returns the original class tree. As is, this will not detect duplicate method names, and strips away modifiers (the compiler would not let me match annotations and modifiers at the same time).

This can easily be expanded to handle companion objects as well, but I left them out to keep the code smaller. See the [quasiquotes syntax summary](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/syntax-summary.html) for the matchers I used. Handling companion objects would require modifying the `result` match to handle `case classDef :: objDef :: Nil`, and case `objDef :: Nil`.

In use:

```
@aliased
class Socket {
    @alias("ask", "read")
    def load(n: Int): Seq[Byte] = Seq(1, 2, 3).map(_.toByte)
}

scala> val socket = new Socket
socket: Socket = Socket@7407d2b8

scala> socket.load(5)
res0: Seq[Byte] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> socket.ask(5)
res1: Seq[Byte] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> socket.read(5)
res2: Seq[Byte] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

It can also handle multiple parameter lists:

```
@aliased
class Foo {
    @alias("bar", "baz")
    def test(a: Int, b: Int)(c: String) = a + b + c
}

scala> val foo = new Foo
foo: Foo = Foo@3857a375

scala> foo.baz(1, 2)("4")
res0: String = 34
```

Comment: For some reason the `!` method was copied over, but wouldn't work. I suspect because it's a special character and needs some sort of special handling, but I don't have time at the moment to find out exactly why.