# Alias a Java method in Scala

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

Given a Java interface

```
interface Value {

  Value add(Value argument);

}
```

(since Java does not support symbols like + as method names), is it possible to define an alias method `+` to alias `add` such that, when the class is used from Scala one can write

```
  result = value1 + value2
```

instead of

```
  result = value1.add(value2)
```

or

```
  result = value1 add value2
```

The alias should apply automatically to all classes implementing the interface.

Comment: I was going to suggest `scala.annotation.alpha` in Dotty, but that apparently doesn't work - it doesn't override the actual add method, but when an add method and an operator with the same alias are made, it says there's a double definition https://scastie.scala-lang.org/UvqrkDFjSXmp9yOYIRSNCg, which is weird

Comment: See this very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279472/use-scala-macros-to-generate-methods

Comment: @user you can't annotate Java interface with Scala macro annotation.

Comment: @DmytroMitin No, but you can annotate Scala classes implementing those interfaces and probably generate those methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add external method extension via [implicit class](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html)

```scala
object ValueImplicits {

  implicit class ValueOps(val value: Value) extends AnyVal {
    def +(v: Value): Value = value.add(v)
  }

}
```

Now it can work like this

```
import ValueImplicits._

val v1 = new Value {}
val v2 = new Value {}
val v3 = v1 + v2
```

You can avoid the import if you can create a companion object for interface `Value` in the same package.

```
object Value {

  implicit class ValueOps(val value: Value) extends AnyVal {
    def +(v: Value): Value = value.add(v)
  }

}
```

[Implicit resolution](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html#companion-objects-of-a-type) checks companion objects without any explicit import.

Comment: Companion is not just an object with same name as class/trait and in the same package. It must be in the same scope and in the same file. Otherwise it's just an object with same name but not companion. So nobody can create companion object for Java interface.